# What is the sequence of code execution in a rspec test file?

Tags: rspec

For the purpose of my question, I'll just explain what the execution sequence is doing in my test by printing messages.

```
describe Something do
  2.times do
    puts "Instruction A"
    it "test" do
      puts "Instruction B"
    end
    puts "Instruction C" 
  end
end
```

I would expect the code to print: 
Instruction A -
Instruction B -
Instruction C -
Instruction A -
Instruction B -
Instruction C

But I am seeing the following sequence:
Instruction A -
Instruction C -
Instruction A -
Instruction C -
Instruction B -
Instruction B

Seems to me that executes the code outside the "it" blocks, putting the blocks in a queue. When it finishes, goes ahead and executes the "it" blocks located in a queue. Is this sequence correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's correct. The `it` blocks are the actual tests and they only get run after all the `describe` blocks have been executed.